# Keeping combinations that contain specific range of values

Tags: r

I want to keep the combination that contains 8 values from 1:30, 1 or 2 values from 31:60, and 3 values from 61:70,

and I have the following combinations :

```
15 6 10 26 7 27 19 51 54 61 64 69 70 
# do not keep this b/c there are 4 values from 61:70

23 2 7 29 3 17 4 20 60 56 61 66 68 # keep this one

17 30 24 3 25 5 15 11 43 49 66 67 68 # keep this one

25 13 14 9 29 16 15 4 56 63 66 67 70 
# do not keep this b/c there are 4 values from 61:70

14 24 3 17 11 15 27 25 31 59 62 65 69

20 28 8 24 1 18 25 3 44 45 69 61 70

... (32 in totals)
```

how can i do this ?
edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to "keep" the required combinations, but to find the combinations you are looking for you can do something like

```
v <- c(15,6,10,26,7,27,19,51,54,61,64,69,70)

if(sum(v>=1 & v<= 30) == 8 &
   sum(v>=31 & v<= 60) %in% c(1L, 2L) &
   sum(v>=61 & v<= 70) == 3){TRUE}
else{FALSE}
```

Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out that the second condition should accept multiple values.

Comment: Close, but the second range needs to be `%in% c(1L, 2L)` I think.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks ! But I think he's right cuz I  have made some editing

Comment: however, what is L in c(1L, 2L) ?

Comment: @Mathygroupy - i don't think he is right, because if you want 1 or 2 values, you need to test for that, not just `==2`. The `L` is for an integer. `1L` is exactly one for when you are comparing counts.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, i agree.  I have edited my answer.